# Access system clock from free pascal on mac osx?

Tags: macos, clock, freepascal

All I want to do is grab system clock values so that I can measure the time between them in order to compare the speeds of alternate codings using Free Pascal on Mac with OSX.

Free Pascal's documentation is more about dates and gross time stamps than about system clocks, as far as I can gather from their online documentation. System clock values would be far more precise.

My research here in stackoverflow finds nothing specific to my situation.

I have been able to do this with Xcode in a native OSX application, but I'd like to use Free Pascal for this app, due to its cross platform portability.

Has anyone found how to do what I need?  Thank you.

Comment: It appears you're looking for `mach_absolute_time` in libc, which Delphi's cross-platform support wraps in the System.Diagnostics unit in `TStopWatch`. That may give you something to look for in FP.

Comment: @Ken Thank you. You set me on a path that eventually got to the EpikTimer unit in Lazarus. I find that it is easy to implement (see primitives below), but seems to have a resolution in microseconds. Ok but the routines I'm testing need an even finer resolution. I will continue to see if EpikTimer can be adjusted to finer resolution. Lazarus also has FPTimer but it's not so easy to implement, although I may end up there.

       uses EpikTimer;
       T :extended;
       EpkTime := TEpikTimer.Create(nil);  EpkTime.Clear;
       EpkTime.Start;  ...  T := EpkTime.Elapsed
       EpkTime.Free;

Comment: Took too long to edit the foregoing, sorry for the crushed code.

Comment: If that works for you, you should post it as an answer in the space below instead of in a comment. [Answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Ken White: FPC does not support Delphi non Windows libs, except for a deprecated Kylix libc unit. Specially since FPC/Lazarus follow the VCL Application framework also on non Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The function for this is [gettickcount64](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/gettickcount64.html), but afaik that hasn't switch to clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC) yet on OS X and still uses fpgettimeofday

It seems that mach_absolute_time is not exposed anywhere, but you may be can declare the import yourself. You also might want to check the univint header for Carbon system functions. Maybe one of the MIDI or (Core)Audio headers there has something for precise timekeeping

Comment: Contrary to FPC documentation, neither gettickcount nor gettickcount64 are supported in sysutils. The compile error is that the identifier is not found. Where else (what other unit) might support it/them? Thanks.

Comment: Sysutils, I checked the fixes branch (3.0.x series for post 3.0.0 fixes) The Classes.TThread class also has a method returning it. Anyway as said for OS X it is not that interesting since it uses plain old clock on OS X

Answer (score 0):

So I pretty much solved my problem by writing a function which uses inline assembler code. The low order longint portion of the counter is sufficient for my purpose. If the counter would happen accumulate into the high order 32 bits during a test run, my subtraction of start from end values would deliver a negative answer, so I'd run the test again. Unfortunately, the clock tick difference includes the ticks during background processes, so I need to minimize active processes during testing.

```
        function HdweTick: longint; assembler;
        asm
            RDTSC
            movl %eax,__result
        end;
```

If you really need 64 bits of clock tick count, you could do this:

```
        function HdweTick: int64;
        type  truc = record
                case ovlay: integer of
                0: (eax, edx :longint);
                1: (val64    :int64  );
              end;
        var   trec :truc;
        begin
            asm
                RDTSC
                movl %eax,trec.eax
                movl %edx,trec.edx
            end;
            HdweTick := trec.val64;
        end;
```